# Publish React 16 component from nx

Tags: reactjs, npm, publish, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I would like to use the nx monorepo to publish a library, which uses React 16. Would I have to use the @nrwl/react plugin, which corresponds to React 16?

I have tried different versions of the @nrwl/react plugin. I have also tried installing React 16 and using it with the latest @nrwl/react plugin.